# Why i have trouble using the state updater function while using useState hook?

Tags: reactjs

While using "const [count, setCount] = useState(0)" useState as so i thought the setCount function is a simple function to update the test variable. But it turns i can't work with it unless i use it in the jsx as so  <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>

here's what i tried and it shows no result but blank on the display

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  setCount(1);
  return (
    <div> {test + 1} A simple div </div>
  );
}
```

i thought it would display "2 A simple div" but nothing displays.

however this code works

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
return (
  <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
        </button>
  </div>
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when state update react component re-render.

update the state directly inside the component function re-render the component again. when it re-render again state update function is called so it went into an infinite loop so it renders nothing.